# How to draw a Divider Line with Name Title before the output display

Tags: printf

I have written a script which displays Name and department of the user and that works.Moreover i am trying to draw a divider line with Name title assign to the columns as they needed. I am trying to do it with printf but somehow not able to get it as of now.. any help will be appreciated..

below is the script and expected result..

```
#!/bin/sh
for names in `cat namefile`;

do

DATA1="`/grid/common/bin/cod -u $names | awk -F: '/Department/ {print $2}'`"
DATA2="`/grid/common/bin/cod -u $names | awk -F: '/Name/ {print $2}'`"

#printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMN'S:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
printf "%-50s : %10s\n" "$DATA2" "$DATA1"
done
bash-4.1$ sh Userdetail.sh
        Karn Kumar                                 :   TT, Infra, VM & India
        Manas .                                    :   TT, Infra, VM & India
        Pranjal Agrawal                            :   TT, Infra, VM & India
        Rogen Mana                                 :   PP OPS-Brazil
```

I'm trying to find a way draw a line with Titles before the output will display like below expected:

```
  Name                                         Department
```

### --------------------------------------------------

```
Karn Kumar                                 :   TT, Infra, VM & India
Manas .                                    :   TT, Infra, VM & India
Pranjal Agrawal                            :   TT, Infra, VM & India
Rogen Mana                                 :   PP OPS-Brazil
```

> Just for more how to know on the command part..

```
bash-4.1$ /grid/common/bin/cod -u karn
        Name:        Karn Kumar
        Title:       IT -Staff Systems Engineer

        Department:  TT, Infra, VM & India
        Mgr:         KK LIN
        Mgr Login:   ttlin
        E-Mail:      karn@abc.com
        Phone:       09999999999
        Internal #:  
        Ext:         4848
        Cell:        8777880559
        Fax:            -
        Building:    NOIDA 03
        Floor:       03
        Room:        3.3.109
```

Comment: Also, side comment: please avoid using the backtick for command substitution use `$( command )` instead. It makes it much easier to read and avoids certain problems. In addition , don't use `for variable in $(cat file.txt)`. There  are other, better ways to read a file line-by-line. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `printf "%-50s : %10s\n" "$DATA2" "$DATA1"` , which tells me in total you will have 63-character wide line (including spaces and `:`). Thus we will want to `printf "%63s"` string. Simple approach is to print spaces and then convert them all to `-` like so

```
printf "%60s" " " | tr ' ' '-'
```

We certainly could use [simpler approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/3701431), but it is specific to `bash`. We can, however, modify it slightly:

```
printf "=%.0s"  $(seq 1 63)
```

This will work in any shell and system that has `seq` installed.

Thus, print the header before going into the loop. For example, here's very very simple case:

```
$ cat ./print_header.sh                                                                                           
#!/bin/bash
# print header
printf "%-50s : %10s\n" "Name"  "Department"
# print separator
printf "=%.0s"  $(seq 1 63)
# insert a newline
printf "\n"
# and this is where your for loop would begin.
# just for the sake of example, there's only one line
printf "%-50s : %10s\n" "John Doe"  "IT,Infra"
$ ./print_header.sh                                                                                               
Name                                               : Department
===============================================================
John Doe                                           :   IT,Infra
```

Comment: thanks for the trick , but how to fit that into the expected results .

Comment: using this , it adds a "-" line before every output display'd.

Comment: @Karn I'll add a simple example. I don't have the input file that you're using, so I'll just make something up

Comment: @Karn answer edited

Comment: i see that, i have also edited the command output which i'm parsing the desired output and having them into DATA1 & DATA2 vars.